HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException in REST API
Getting
o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.logException - Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------917244744405307766670554;charset=UTF-8' not supported]

for below code
@PostMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,consumes =
        MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,value = "/{userId}")
@Override
public ResponseEntity<WarrantyDetailsRequestResponse> createWarrantyDetails
        (@RequestBody UsersWarrantyDetailsDTO usersWarrantyDetails,
         @PathVariable("userId") Long userId,
         @RequestParam("qrCodeImage") MultipartFile qrCodeImage,
         @RequestParam("productInvoice") MultipartFile productInvoice,
         @RequestParam("other_files") MultipartFile[] otherProductFiles) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(warrantyDetailsRequestResponse, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

Sending multipart form data request from Postman, handled all files data properly but still Spring Boot reports
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------917244744405307766670554;charset=UTF-8' not supported]


I think you should be using MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA for the value of consumes in @PostMapping, not MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE.

Remove the produces and consumes from the @PostMapping.

You must remove consumes and produces from @PostMapping
and replace @RequestBody with @ModelAttribute.
